# How to get latitude and longitude from android devide?

Tags: android, google-maps, kotlin

I have an app that is already asking for runtime permissions to activate the localization permission and I have all ready to receive longitude and latitude. My problem now is only to get the latitude and longitude from the device itself.

This is my method, assume that the method goes to the else statement because I already have the permissions handling working

```
 if (!checkPermissions()) {
        requestPermissions()
    } else {

        //get latitude and long here
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a sample code

1.LocationManager & Listener

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
```

2.Setting manager & Listener

```
locationManager = (LocationManager)this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

locationListener = new LocationListener() {
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
}

locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, locationListener);
    String locationProvider = LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER;
    currentLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(locationProvider);
    if (currentLocation != null) {
        double lng = currentLocation.getLongitude();
        double lat = currentLocation.getLatitude();
        Log.d("Log", "longtitude=" + lng + ", latitude=" + lat);
    }
```